# Pick which list to reference via the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a non-monobehaviour class containing lists, set in stone at compile time. I have some monobehaviour code that needs to be reusable, which takes one of those lists and modifies it. I would like to be able to pick which list gets modified via the inspector, but I can't find a good google answer to get me there.

Preferably, I will be able to add Lists to the non-monobehaviour without modifying the code responsible for selecting the list.

Any tips?

Examples of the lists to be modified:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BOAT
{
    public List<BlockScriptableObject> DefendInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();
    public List<BlockScriptableObject> AssistInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();
    public List<BlockScriptableObject> MiscInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();
}
```

Comment: is the number and variety of lists known at compile time or are they stored in something like a dictionary of lists? The question is very vague and broad as written. If you provided an example source code of a non-monobehaviour class you would like to do this to, that would help narrow down the question.

Comment: Added the relevant code above, they are indeed set when the code is compiled, not created dynamically.

Comment: I haven't done much with custom editors, but I would try using reflection to get the names of the list fields in `BOAT`, then populate a [dropdown](https://answers.unity.com/questions/458987/dropdownlist-with-string-array-in-editor-inspector.html) with those names. then on selection, use reflection to get a reference to the corresponding `BOAT.XYZ` list from the name, then assign it to some `List<BlockScriptableObject> targetList;` field on the monobehavior, which is the list reference that the method performs its modifications on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would **not recommend** using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) here as suggested by others!

Reflection is always quite slow and especially when you are going to access and change values in your list on a frame basis it is not the best idea.

The one (and only) advantage ofcourse: (Once you finally have implemented the required reflection and additional EditorScript!) the options are filled in automatically for every list in the class.

The huge drawback: You have to repeat this and implement a new editor script every time a MonoBehaviour needs this functionality.

---

You could use a simple `enum` and a `Dictionary` instead which comes with a minimal overhead of adding the according list names to the `enum` and to the `Dictionary` like

```
[Serializable]
public class BOAT
{
    public enum ListType
    {
        DefendInventory,
        AssistInventory,
        MiscInventory
    }

    public List<BlockScriptableObject> DefendInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();
    public List<BlockScriptableObject> AssistInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();
    public List<BlockScriptableObject> MiscInventory = new List<BlockScriptableObject>();

    public Dictionary<ListType, List<BlockScriptableObject>> ListByType;

    // Initialize the Dictionary in the default constructor
    public BOAT()
    {
        ListByType = new Dictionary<ListType, List<BlockScriptableObject>>
        {
            {ListType.DefendInventory, DefendInventory},
            {ListType.AssistInventory, AssistInventory},
            {ListType.MiscInventory, MiscInventory}
        };
    }
}
```

Then for accessing and changing a specific list you set the enum type via the inspector in your script

```
// gives you a Dropdown for available ListType values
// in the Inspector
public BOAT.ListType listToChange;

...

var listToBeChanged = someBoat.ListByType[listToChange];
```

Using this the Inspector handles it all for you automatically and it works in the Editor and at runtime without any further overhead.

---

Little demo code

```
public class blarf : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BOAT.ListType listToChange;
    public BOAT boat;

    public List<BlockScriptableObject> currentList;

    // only for the demo (later you would rather do this in a Property)
    // update the current accessed and changed list according to the 
    // selected ListType
    private void Update()
    {
        currentList = boat.ListByType[listToChange];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the reflection would only need to be done when the list name is changed in the editor? On every frame, the list could be referenced just by reading the `List<BlockScriptableObject>` field, not by using reflection. I don't see why reflection is bad if you're doing it O(1) times per interaction with the inspector.

Comment: @Ruzihm 1. very usecase specific .. maybe not good in a general case where the `listToChange` value is dynamically changed later ;) 2. I didn't say it was bad or forbidden .. I just said I wouldn't recommend it in general .. and also not in this case because you are dealing with a beginner  ;) I would rather not throw him into EditorScripting and Reflection where it is really not necessary .. 3. Using reflection you only gain a very small advantage of having the options updated automatically when introducing a new list in the code... but that's already all your gain => `I would not recommend`

Comment: That's a fair answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might try using C# Reflection and editor customization to automatically populate the dropdown with the names of your fields. Assume each field you might want to target ends with "Inventory".

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ModifierMB))]
public class ModifierMBEditor : Editor
{
    public SerializedProperty nameOfListToEdit;

    void OnEnable() {
        nameOfListToEdit = serializedObject.FindProperty("nameOfListToEdit");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        serializedObject.Update();
        // use Reflection to get the names of the fields
        string[] fieldNames = typeof(ModifierMB).GetFields()
            .Select(field => field.Name)
            .Where(name => name.EndsWith("Inventory"))
            .ToArray();
        int index = 0;
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, fieldNames);
        nameOfListToEdit.stringValue = fieldNames[index];
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Then, in the MonoBehavior...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;

public class ModifierMB : MonoBehavior
{
    string nameOfListToEdit;

    BOAT objectContainingLists;

    public void ModifyLists() {
        FieldInfo fieldToEdit = typeof(objectContainingLists).GetField(nameOfListToEdit);
        List<BlockScriptableObject> listToEdit = fieldToEdit.GetValue(objectContainingLists);
        // modify listToEdit here ################
        Debug.Log(listToEdit);
        // #######################################
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't an ideal solution, because it uses Reflection every time you want to modify the list. Reflection is generally very slow and inefficient, you might want to find a way to cache the List that is going to be edited. For example, you could do the Reflection when the MonoBehavior is initialized, and then cache the `listToEdit` in a field, to be accessed/modified later.

Caching the `listToEdit` in a field could be done along these lines:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ModifierMB))]
public class ModifierMBEditor : Editor
{
    public SerializedProperty nameOfListToEdit;

    void OnEnable() {
        nameOfListToEdit = serializedObject.FindProperty("nameOfListToEdit");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        serializedObject.Update();
        // use Reflection to get the names of the fields
        string[] fieldNames = typeof(ModifierMB).GetFields()
            .Select(field => field.Name)
            .Where(name => name.EndsWith("Inventory"))
            .ToArray();
        int index = 0;
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, fieldNames);
        nameOfListToEdit.stringValue = fieldNames[index];
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        ModifierMB modifier = (ModifierMB)target; 
        modifier.listToEdit = typeof(modifier.objectContainingLists).GetField(
                                      fieldNames[index]).GetValue(
                                              modifier.objectContainingLists);
    }
}
```

Then, in the MonoBehavior...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;

public class ModifierMB : MonoBehavior
{
    string nameOfListToEdit;

    public BOAT objectContainingLists;

    public List<BlockScriptableObject> listToEdit;

    public void ModifyLists() {
        // modify listToEdit here ################
        Debug.Log(listToEdit);
        // #######################################
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looked at the comments on the question... I think this is more or less the same solution @Ruzihm was talking about.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much! One difference though. Is there a way to make `listToEdit` a field in `ModifierMB` that is set only when the inspector changes? That way you can call `ModifyLists` on every frame without having to call `GetField` and `GetValue` every frame. Edit: I just realized that this is what your last paragraph is getting at lol

Comment: My thought was to make `listToEdit` a field, and just initialize it via Reflection in `Awake()`, that way it'll only run at startup, once per each object. Still, that might cause a pretty big delay at startup if there's a lot of objects... Your suggestion is better; I'm not sure how to set references from the Inspector/Editor though. Maybe someone else knows how this is done?

Comment: Maybe this at the end of  `OnInspectorGUI`: `ModifierMB modifier = target as ModifierMB;` `modifier.listToEdit = typeof(objectContainingLists).GetField(fieldNames[index]).GetValue(modifier.objectContainingLists);` ?

Comment: That might work! Though I'm not sure if you can interact directly with MonoBehavior fields in the Inspector, or do you need to go through the SerializedProperties? I don't have Unity available at the moment, but @James if you try this could you let us know if it works? :)

Comment: @James I added the changes discussed in the comments above at the end of the answer if you want to try those

Answer (score 1):

Make a public int and use it as an index, check when it changes and attribute the desired list.

```
    public int Index;
    private int currentIndex;

    void Update()
    {
       // Check if was updated
       if(Index != currentIndex)
       {
          currentIndex = Index ;

          switch(Index)
         { 
            case 1:
            currestList = DefendInventory ;
             break;
         ...
         }
       }
    }
```

You can use an enum instead of an int for a dropdown in the inspector.

Comment: While a good idea, I need the script to be generic. This method still requires me to manually update it every time I add a list to the non-monodevelop class.

Comment: I might well be using this script across a great many similar situations.

Comment: What do you mean with "update the method every frame"?

Comment: I don't mean "update with every frame", more I have to manually enter the target in every situation I add a list to the non-monodevelop class. This wotn happen at runtime, but it might well have lists added as development continues.